# Higher mean and lower covariance

Tags: statistics, covariance, means

[image]
I am confused. Isn't the mean of both plans the same? And how am I supposed to find the values of mean, variance and correlation? There is no value given in the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
For random variable X and Y, and constants a, b

$\qquad\mathsf{E}(aX+bY)=a\mathsf{E}(X)+b\mathsf{E}(Y)$

$\qquad\mathsf{Var}(aX+bY)=a^2\mathsf{Var}(X)+b^2\mathsf{Var}(Y)+2ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$

1) To find Cov, use relation between Cov and Corr?

2) Plan 1 is 2X+2Y...

Comment: But both X and Y have the same mean, shouldn't it be the same for both plans?

Comment: Yes, for same means the person would prefer lower variance, so, it boils down to who would have lower var.

Comment: But how to find values for them?

Comment: Oh I think I got it. I'll get two formulas for the variance of two plans, and I need to force the second one to be smaller than the first one. But still, I can't find the value of the mean, since they are the same.

Comment: And I only know that the correlation is between -1 and 1, so how to find Cov according to that information?

Comment: http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Covariance.html

Comment: Yep I've seen the formula for Cov and Cor. But in the problem, it only says Cor is somewhere between -1 and 1, instead of a number. So how to find the value of Cov?

Comment: Consider the 2 cases when the corr is +ve and -ve?

Comment: The correlation can only be -1 or 1?

Comment: @J.doe No, those are the extremes.  Examine the behaviour between.

Comment: but there are infinite values between -1 and 1...

Comment: To find a value for the variance, I think we need to know the value of Cor? Since variance changes with Cor?